# jqgrid with custom column

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I am using Jqgrid in my application. I wanted to create a column with 2 buttons. I want to have in column since the buttons may differ based on the data of the row. I googled it and I am able to found only creating a button using custom formatter option, but it appears only on double clicking a row or on edit of a row, but I want it to be displayed on column itself. Any help or link containing information will be appreciated. Below is my grid code. 
Need to create an another column with buttons.

**Edit:**

```
var grid = $(gridId);
grid.jqGrid({
    data: gridData,
    datatype: "local",
    gridview: true,
    colModel: [
        {
            label: 'Employee Name', name: 'employeeName', width: 195, editable:true,
            sortable:true, editrules:{required:true}
        },
        {
            label: 'Address', name: 'address', width: 170, editable:true,
            sortable:true,
            editrules:{required:true}
        },
        {
            label: 'Department', name: 'department', width: 120, editable:true,
            sortable:true,
            edittype:'custom',
            editoptions: {
                'custom_element' : populateReturnTypeAutocomplete,
                'custom_value' : autocomplete_value
                },
            editrules:{required:true}
        },
  });
```

Comment: A custom formatter should meet your needs, please edit your question and add the code for the grid declaration and custom formatter and we will be better able to assist you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay add this to your colModal

```
{label: 'My Custom Column', name: 'custom', index:'custom' width: 120}
```

Now in gridComplete or loadComplete add this code

```
var grid =  $("#grid"),
         iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid,'custom'); // 'custom' - name of the actions column
         grid.children("tbody")
                .children("tr.jqgrow")
                .children("td:nth-child("+(iCol+1)+")")
                .each(function() {
                 $("<div>",
                        {
                            title: "button1",
                            mouseover: function() {
                                $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                            },
                            mouseout: function() {
                                $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                            },
                            click: 
                            handle your click function here
                            }
                      ).css({"margin-left": "5px", float:"left"})
                       .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-save")
                       .attr('id',"customId")
                       .append('<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span>')
                       .appendTo($(this).children("div"));




$("<div>",
                            {
                                title: "custombutton 2",
                                mouseover: function() {
                                    $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                                },
                                mouseout: function() {
                                    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                                },
                                click: 
                                handle click here
                                }
                          ).css({"margin-left": "5px", float:"left"})
                           .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-custom")
                           .attr('id',"customButton2")
                           .append('<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check"></span>')
                           .appendTo($(this).children("div"));
```

Now these icons I'm adding here will be available with jquery ui.css and you will have to add one more function to your script which will get 'custom' column index for u in line first of above code.

```
var getColumnIndexByName = function(grid,columnName) {
                var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel'), i=0,l=cm.length;
                for (; i<l; i+=1) {
                    if (cm[i].name===columnName) {
                        return i; // return the index
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            };
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Piyush Sardana. Your code really helped me. This is what I was looking for.